# Libgdx, Gradle, android package naming problem

Tags: libgdx, gradle

I'm upgrading my libgdx project to make use of all the new Gradle stuff.

However I changed the package namespace from the default generated by gdx-setup but that hasn't worked: when I debug to my phone Gradle is still trying to launch the default activity using the old namespace, hence it fails. But I can't figure out where Gradle is getting this from - I've searched the entire folder tree for the offending old namespace string and can't find it anywhere.

Details:

So gdx-setup generated the android project with namespace "com.wibble.mygame.android"

To match the namespace of my already-published game, I edited that to "com.wibble.mygame_a". I did this in the Android.manifest and the source code. Also noticed that the android build.gradle file has a line that generates the am start command so corrected that as well.

But when I debug with my connected Android device, it tries to launch the app with a command like:

```
am start -n "com.wibble.mygame.android/com.wibble.mygame_a.AndroidLauncher" 
   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

the old namespace is still there but I can't figure out where its getting it from because I can't find any mention of 'mygame.android' anywhere in the whole project tree. Is there some cache of stuff hidden somewhere that I need to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing out the IntelliJ project and files and re-importing from the gradle.build solved the problem. IntelliJ must have been caching something somewhere.